# Whitespace getting returned before echo

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, echo

*NOTE: I'm autoloading classes with an auto-loading script incase you were wondering why there isn't an include on the class files*

I'm writing some php to interact via ajax, and have some code that will return close if criteria is not met. with Jquery after the data is returned, I want to check if the data is equal to close, but I'm getting the close string with whitespace in front of it returned.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#extra-actions-bar img").click(function(){
        var a = $(this).data('action');
        var b = $("#csrf-token").text();
        $.post( "/auth/administrativeActions",{ "action" : a,"csrf" : b }, function( data ) {
                console.log(data);
                if(data == "close"){
                    window.location.href = 'http://www.###########.com';
                }
                displayResult(data);
            });
    });
});
```

I've narrowed down the problem but Im not sure whats causing it. If i put my in my echo and exit before I initiate my class It works fine and doesn't return whitespace, but if I echo it after I do get whitespace.

I get whitespace if I use this

```
$user = new userFunc;
$sess = $user->validSess("bool");
$actions = new administrativeActions;
echo "close";
exit();
```

I don't get whitespace if I use this

```
$user = new userFunc;
$sess = $user->validSess("bool");
echo "close";
exit();
$actions = new administrativeActions;
```

And this is my class that gets called

```
<?php
/**
    *   Class: Handles all actions available from the adminBar
    *
    *
    *
    *
    */
class administrativeActions{


        private $conx;

    public function __construct() {
        include("".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/auth/db_conx.php");
        $this->conx = $conx;
    }


        /*
        Name: ownerActions()
        Param: NONE
        Output: HTML based on requested service 
        */
        function ownerActions(){
            echo "YOU ARE DA REAL MVP";
        }

}
?>
```

but as you can see, no white space is being output, I'm a little stuck with this one :(

Any help is appreciated... cheers!

Comment: Is there further code in your class file? if not, try removing the closing PHP tag `?>`

Comment: That fixed the problem! Do you know why this is the case?

Comment: There must have been some white space after the closing tag, this way ensures you wont run into that error @thomas

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing exit(); to exit; ?

Comment: This doesn't matter. Either way is valid, so is `die();` or just `die;` - This is really a comment though.

Comment: Also maybe try using die(); as an alternative if you really cannot work it out. But i see no reason at all for echo to have an added whitespace before it.

Comment: Thats what i was thinking Fred. Makes no sence why he would get whitespace when he is simply using echo on a static text string.

Comment: It might even be caused by a closing `?>` tag. I've seen that happen many times before.

Comment: I was right  about the `?>` tag. Read the comments under OP's question.

Comment: Actually now you say it yes i have had this when calling a file from jquery and using the returned data as output. Maybe he has the script in a file that is included via ajax.

Comment: Not necessarily but you're partially right. jQuery isn't always the culprit. This is most likely to happen when using classes.